# getting web page data as json object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xss

I have a url, the data of which page i need as a json object.
I ve tried xmlhttprequest and ajaxobject both but doesnt work. It doesnt even give a responseText when I give it as an alert
Ill post both the code snippets here. `url = http://mydomain.com:port/a/b/c`

**AJAX :**

```
var ajaxRequest = new ajaxObject(URL);

ajaxRequest.callback = function (responseText,responseStatus) {

  alert(responseStatus); 

  JSONData = responseText.parseJSON();

  processData(JSONData);
}
```

**USING xmlhttprequest:**

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open('GET',URL,true );

data = JSON.parse(client.responseText);

alert(data.links.length);
```

can someone please help me out with this. I understand cross scripting may be an issue, but how to come over it? and shouldn't then too it should give the alerts as zero or null

Comment: Is the server returning correct content type `application/json` ?

Comment: @Rosdi how do I set/check that?
Also should it not atleast return zero/null or a statuscode of 0.. the problem is that its not showing anything

Comment: Check my answer below, it is too long to type in comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar like this previously, where jquery had trouble reading the response because the server is returning content type `text/html` instead of `application/json`

If you don't set it, the default will be `text/html`.

If you use php, this is how you set it,

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If you use jsp, this is how to set it,

```
response.setContentType('application/json');
```

This must be done before you are writing the response to client.

Install firebug and it lets you see the actual content-type being returned.

Make sure yours is `application/json`.

Comment: this worked! I also set the accept type as application/json
with both statements it worked for me!
Thanks rosdi and jamie

Comment: Good to hear that.., don't forget to mark my answer as accepted answer so that I can brag to my mom.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a bit of an assuption here and say that you're trying to load data from a *different* domain using ajax?

If this is the case, you wont be able to do it using a standard ajax request. There are some services out there such as: http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ which aim to help overcome this when necessary.

[Calling Cross Domain Web Services in AJAX](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) also has some useful information on how you can configure the remote domain to accept incoming requests etc.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: @jamie should it not atleast return zero/null or a statuscode of 0.. the problem is that its not showing anything. do you still think its to do with the cross domain scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [LitJSON](http://litjson.sourceforge.net/).

> LitJSON is a small and fast library
>   for handling data in the JSON format.
>   It is written in C# and is compatible
>   with all .Net languages.